# How to authenticate User on force.com site/ How to maintain session

Tags: force.com-sites

I've created a force.com site, which has custom login and register functionality.

When any person register on website, I will store his details on contact object as a record.

When person login on website, I will check for the entered data is available as a contact record or not. If contact available, I will allow person to login on my website.

suppose my login page URL like  :
https://MyDomainName-developer-edition.na6.force.com/Logistic/customerlogin

when person will logged in successfully. My link will like this:
https://MyDomainName-developer-edition.na6.force.com/Logistic/viewcustomer?Id=003P0000019fVHOIA2

Now my question is when i open this link anywhere it shows that the person is logged in. means anyone can hack data here.

How to maintain the security of customer.
I'm not sure what is work around to resolve this. or we have to maintain session. If we've to use session then  how?

Please Guide me on this scenario.

Comment: Setup a customer / partner community. Also on the force site there is an option to require login. Do not try to handle the login/session yourself. Let the platform do it.

Comment: @Eric. Can you please give me Ideas/link of the flow, how can I manage my website. Which will we helpful for me.